# Converting Buildings into PolygonZ using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am new to ArcGIS.

I want to convert buildings of a city into PolygonZ.  The map is taken from google maps.

How do I do that?

Comment: My data are in KML format.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications and any information that may be relevant to your brief question.

Answer (score 1):

Load the kml file into global mapper and go to File --> Export with "Generate 3D features using loaded elevation data" option checked, to export it as a shape file  [image]

In this case, if you have elevation data like DEM already loaded in global mapper then it will automatically assign elevation values using it. Otherwise, it will create you a "POLYGONZ" with '0' elevation values. So you have to assign elevation values for each and every vertex manually using Arcgis or Qgis.